# Appear data in URL form bu using Django

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I want to create a record and want to appear data in the form fields. How can I do that ? Do I need to write javascript for it. If you help me, really apprepriate it. Thanks for now.

Here is models.py;

```
class hesaplarim(models.Model):
    hesap_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tc_no = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Here is views.py;

```
def home(request):
    form = HesapForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = HesapForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is forms.py;

```
class HesapForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ERKEK = 'ERKEK'
    KADIN = 'KADIN'
    gender_choices = (
        (ERKEK, 'ERKEK'),
        (KADIN, 'KADIN')
    )
    tc_no = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    surname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=gender_choices)

    class Meta:
        model = hesaplarim
        fields = ('tc_no', 'name', 'surname', 'phone_number', 
    'gender')
```

Here is html file;

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_tc_no">TC No:</label>
    {{ form.tc_no }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_name">Ad:</label>
    {{ form.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_surname">Soyad:</label>
  {{ form.surname }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_phone">Cep Telefonu:</label>
    {{ form.phone_number }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_gender">Cinsiyet:</label>
    {{ form.gender }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Kaydet">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the form:

```
def home(request):
    form = HesapForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = HesapForm(initial={'your_field': 'your_value'})
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

[Dynamic initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) you can refer about the same here.
You can also initialize it with object as well.